# Javascript - Access PHP session variable after ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i got two files one is productlisting.php and another is producttree.php (this one is ajax file).

i got one session variable in ajax file producttree.php

```
 $checktotalrecords=$_SESSION['totalnoofrecondfound'];
```

i would like to get above variable value to main productlisting.php file after running ajax.

purpose of above variable to check no of records in ajax, in order to handle next and previous buttons in productlisting.php file.

thanks

Comment: use get or post instead .

Comment: @ArunKillu i done it... but productlisting.php run first thats why i am getting old value...for getting right value i have to click again..

Comment: i guess...this should be done through javascript or jquery...

Comment: when you run for the first time get the new value and keep it a varible and when you call for the second time just use that

Comment: productlisting.php runs once...product tree only changed on clicking (ajax)

Answer (score 0):

in producttree.php:

```
$checktotalrecords=$_SESSION['totalnoofrecondfound'];
//do some stuff to $checktotalrecords

$return = ["checktotalrecords"=>$checktotalrecords]; //add any other variables you want to return as well

echo json_encode($return);
```

in productlisting.php:

I assume you have something like this:

```
$.ajax(...);
```

Change it to something like

```
$.getJSON('producttree.php',{datatosend},function(json){
   var checktotalrecords = json.checktotalrecords;
   //update DOM elements with above value as needed
 });
```